# Liferay server in Spring Tool Suite (STS) gives permission denied error

Tags: eclipse, macos, liferay, tomcat8, spring-tool-suite

Using liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3 on my Mac system El Capitan 10.11, I have setup my Liferay 7.x server in Spring Tool Suite. It has tomact 8 server included in it. I have included Liferay IDE in my STS and generated Liferay Plugin Project but  when I am trying to run the application I am getting Permission denied exception, which is shown below. I have sudo credentials of my Mac system. How can I get rid of this Permission denied exception while trying to run my application? I have attached the screen shot of the error too.

```
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/remo/Projects/xnet/Development/tools/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/logs/catalina.2016-12-08.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.openWriter(FileHandler.java:384)
    at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:96)
    at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:71)
    at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:562)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:505)
    at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:309)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:399)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:396)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:396)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(LogManager.java:145)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:345)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.util.ClassLogger.<init>(ClassLogger.java:55)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.<clinit>(ConnectorBootstrap.java:846)
    at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:257)
    at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:447)
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/remo/Projects/xnet/Development/tools/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/logs/localhost.2016-12-08.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
```

[image: Liferay Server Permissino Denied error]

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you've used your sudo power to start STS/Liferay/Tomcat as root once. Now your logfiles and OSGi state files are owned by root and can't be overwritten when you're starting the server as an unprivileged user.

As it's quite bad practice to run an internet facing server as root, I'd suggest to `sudo chown -r remo /Users/remo/Projects/xnet/Development/tools/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/` (assuming that this is the `chown` syntax on MacOS). This command changes ownership of the files in /Users/remo/Projects/xnet/Development/tools/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/ to your user (remo) recursively (-r)

Starting the server from eclipse typically is done using your own user account and should work then.